# Why does this string comparison give that result in ruby?

Tags: ruby

```
k=[]

path="E:/expr/amit.txt"
name="amit"

File.open("amit.txt").each do |l| 
  k<< l
end

puts k[0]
puts name.eql?("k[0]")
```

O/p 
amit

false

why o/p containing false??it should give true

Comment: I can't read that... Please, edit question using http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: And maybe answer on your question is `puts name.eql?(k[0])`

Comment: Show  your amit.txt file contents if you want us to help you without guessing !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not sure why your program isn't working, `.inspect` is your friend.

```
k=[]

path="E:/expr/amit.txt"
name="amit"

File.open("amit.txt").each do |l|
  puts "Debugging: l is #{l.inspect}"
  k<< l
end

puts k[0]
puts name.eql?("k[0]")
puts "Debugging: name is #{name.inspect}, while k[0] is #{k[0].inspect}"
```

Answer (score 3):

The value of `name` is "amit". You're checking whether the string `"amit"` is equal to the string `"k[0]"`. It's not, so you get false.

What you probably meant to do was `name.eql?(k[0])`, which would check whether the value `k[0]` is `"amit"`. However this would still return false, because `k[0]` is "amit\n", not `"amit"`.

To fix this, you should do `k << l.chomp` instead of `k << l` to remove the trailing `\n`.

Comment: but i also given puts k[0] and that giving amit my file content are

Comment: AMIT: You can't see the `\n` with puts. You should use `p` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Try doing a chomp before you save the `k`

```
k=[]
name="amit"
File.foreach("file") do  |line|
  k<<line.chomp
end
p k.grep(name)
puts name.eql?(k[0])
```

output

```
$ cat file
amit
submit

$ ruby test.rb
["amit"]
true
```

Comment: all in vain i tried with k << l.chomp but still getting false

Comment: why don't you show the contents of your amit.txt file in your question!!?

Comment: yaa sure content of my amit.txt is

Comment: amit                                                                sumit                                                                          this is content of file amit.txt

Comment: means amit and sumit are in two differnt line like                                                                amit                                                                sumit

Comment: sorry am not able to put amit and sumit in two line

Comment: edit your question and put your file content in. That way, others can see it more clearly. And, btw, I don't have any problem with your code. See edit.

Comment: whats happening this is my o/p                                                                  []
false

Comment: running ruby 1.8.6 (2007-03-13 patchlevel 0) [i386-mswin32]

Comment: puts k.grep(name) is printing nothing

Comment: thanks ghost i run this code to some other machine is working there i don't why whenever am running it scite am getting problem any way thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You're testing the string `"amit"` against the string `"k[0]"`. I think you probably want `puts name.eql?(k[0])`